# How to fix screen tearing in cocos3d?

Tags: screen, opengl-es-2.0, cocos3d, tearing

When I get the camera closer to some objects in the scene the image tears apart like it's shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm using OpenglES 2.0

[This](http://tinypic.com/r/15xrdxj/8) is a video showing the issue.

And [this](https://anonfiles.com/file/6f7c7634f601a234fb2751b50b6395d1) is the test project that reproduce the issue, it's just the cocos3d template with the temple.pod file.

**It seems that it only happens when the field of view is 85º or wider.**

Comment: Does this only happen when the camera is moving?

Comment: @MattFichman It does happen in either, when the camera is static and when it is dynamic.

Comment: @rraallw That's odd.  I thought it might be screen tearing (which is fixed by enabling vsync) but apparently not.  I'm not that familiar with cocos3d -- how often does it swap the screen buffer?  Is the rendering loop running/refreshing continuously?

Comment: @MattFichman The rendering loop is a CADisplayLink with NSDefaultRunLoopMode, the screen buffer is swapped once each pass of the rendering loop, I also added a link to the video showing the issue.

Comment: How are you creating your perspective transform?

Comment: @MattFichman Thanks, it was the near clipping plane distance, in the perspective transform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell by running your demo, the "tearing" appears to be occurring as the *near clipping plane* of your camera breaches your model. Essentially, it is a result of the camera entering your model.

The `CC3Camera nearClippingDistance` property controls the distance to the camera's near clipping plane. The default value is `1.0`. If the coordinate scale of your scene is very small, then you should adjust the near and far clipping distances of the camera to values more suitable for your scene.

Comment: Thanks, it was the nearClippingDistance, it was to big for the wallway.